# If $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)\neq X$ then $\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)\neq\{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely compact operators. In the text, the author gives the following proposition:

> **Proposition 1**:
>
> - $(i)$ If $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)=X$ then $\text{ker}(T-\lambda I)=\{0\}$ (or, equivalently, if $\text{ker}(T-\lambda I)\neq \{0\}$ then $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)\neq X$).
> - (ii) Similarly to the above, if $\text{Im}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)=X^*$ then $\text{ker}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)=\{0\}$.

I completely understand **Proposition 1**. The author then gives the following Proposition:

> **Proposition 2**:
>
> - $(i)$ $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)^\perp=\text{ker}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)$, and because $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)$ is a closed subspace, if $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)\neq X$ then $\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)\neq\{0\}$.
> - (ii) $\text{ker}(T-\lambda I)=\text{Im}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)_\perp$ and moreover,
>   $$
>   \text{ker}(T-\lambda I)^\perp=\text{Im}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I).
>   $$

Besides one part, I understand **Proposition 2**. The part of **Proposition 2** I don't understand is $(i)$. More specifically, I don't understand when the author says, "because $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)$ is a closed subspace, if $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)\neq X$ then $\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)\neq\{0\}$". I know that $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)$ is a closed subspace, but I don't see how if $\text{Im}(T-\lambda I)\neq X$ then $\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)\neq\{0\}$. I think either the author stated this incorrectly or makes use of **Proposition 1**...

Comment: The statement is correct, and does not make use of the first proposition

Comment: Recall that if $U$ is a subspace of a Hilbert space, then $(U^{\perp})^{\perp} = \overline U$. Thus, $\operatorname{im}(T-\lambda I)^\perp=\text{ker}(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)$ tells us that
$$\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I) = \{0\} \implies \operatorname{im}(T-\lambda I) = \big( \operatorname{im}(T-\lambda I)^{\perp} \big)^{\perp} = \ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)^{\perp} = \{0\}^\perp = X.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annihilator of $Y \subset X$ is zero iff $\overline{Y} = X$.